# Specify time zone of log4j's date

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, log4j

Is it possible to specify the time zone that log4j will use? I need the dates in the log file to be a different time zone than the application's. log4j's `PatternLayout` uses `SimpleDateFormat`. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to control `SimpleDateFormat`'s time zone via the pattern string (`DateFormat` has `setTimeZone` method but that doesn't help).

I looked at log4j's source and `SimpleDateFormat` is being instiantiated in `PatternParser.finalizeConverter`. Unfortunately there's not an easy way to get a hold of the `DateFormat` to set the time zone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you use the Log4J extras JAR file on your classpath, the EnhancedPatternLayout class supports this configuration option.  See the Javadoc at [this link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html).  It's handled as part of the %d pattern component like this:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{}{America/New_York} %p [%c] - %m%n
```

You can download the extras package [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras).

Comment: In my case in the logger it is coming as {America/New_York} DEBUG [hi] - hi.. I don't know why its not working

Comment: since 1.2.16 it's part of log4j itself

Comment: @khill link is dead

Answer (score 10):

My Case...
must change the patternLayout to EnhancedPatternLayout.
(log4j-1.2.17.jar)

log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.**EnhancedPatternLayout**
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}{GMT+9}]%-5p - %m%n

Answer (score 4):

The log pattern above has right idea but not fully correct (you don't get any timestamp in log).
Use this pattern for sure:
`%d{ISO8601}{America/New_York} %p [%c] - %m%n`

or
`%d{ISO8601}{GMT-5} %p [%c] - %m%n`

Answer (score 3):

It is preferable to use something like {America/New_York} rather than {GMT-5} because by specifying a timezone an automatic adjustment will be made if daylight savings is operational.  Specifying something like GMT-5 will simply adjust the GMT time zone by the specified amount of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you whant to dinamicaly obtein the default time zone, you can extend EnhancedPatternLayout and overwrite the method "setConversionPattern" like this:

```
@Override
public void setConversionPattern(String conversionPattern) {
    String defaultTimeZoneId = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    String conversionPatternModif = conversionPattern.replaceAll(
        "\\%d\\{([^\\{\\}]*)\\}([ ]*[^\\{]*)", 
        "%d{$1}{"+defaultTimeZoneId+"}$2");

    super.setConversionPattern(conversionPatternModif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append the timezone surrounded by curly braces to %d in your [date pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternDate).

E.g. %d{DEFAULT}{America/New_York} instead of %d{DEFAULT}

(In log4j 2 you can use regular PatternLayout. In log4j 1 since 1.2.16, EnhancedPatternLayout is included and recommended.)