# Apache Log4j Logging with specific timezone

Tags: java, timezone, log4j

I want the log should contain date entries of specific timezone. Is there any way of forcing timezone in `log4j.properties`?

Now I am using JDK 1.5, As you already know that there is timezone bug in JDK 1.5 that is removed in JDK 1.5. In case of JDK 1.5 it by default shows "GMT" timezone. I want to configure in Log4j my specific timezone.

Comment: be more specific, how does it look now and how do you want it to look like ?

Comment: @CatalinCiobanu Is it clear now?

Answer (score 19):

This will allow you to see timezone information in each line of your logs:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS/zzz}
```

The trick is to include 'zzz' in the pattern since according to Javadoc for java.text.SimpleDateFormat ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ), that's the code for timezone.  Log4J uses the same rules as SimpleDateFormat.

There are more details over the in the Log4J Javadoc:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Look for the row in the table where the 'Conversion Character' is the letter 'd'.

Comment: it wil always give me GMT in jdk 1.5, thats why I want my specific timezone

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.  In that case here's your solution (needs an "extras" jar):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785725/specify-time-zone-of-log4js-date

Comment: Quoting important part of the `PatternLayout`'s javadoc:  Although part of the standard JDK, the performance of SimpleDateFormat is quite poor.

For better results it is recommended to use the log4j date formatters. These can be specified using one of the strings "ABSOLUTE", "DATE" and "ISO8601" for specifying AbsoluteTimeDateFormat, DateTimeDateFormat and respectively ISO8601DateFormat. For example, %d{ISO8601} or %d{ABSOLUTE}.

Comment: Yeah, but by "quite poor" they mean it can do 10,000 formats per second.  Frankly, if this represents a major performance bottleneck of your app, then you deserve a glass of champagne.

Comment: @JuliusDavies by using extras jar I am not getting any date in the logger. Please suggest

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use the [Apache Extras™ for Apache log4j™](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/) 
And replace The normal PatternLayout by org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout doing the following if using a property file:

```
//log4j.appender.xxx.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
//Replaced by
log4j.appender.xxx.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

Then you can use %d{ISO8601}{GMT} instead of %d in the ConversionPattern to display your date in the GMT format. Any timezone can be specified instead of GMT

Answer (score 3):

There are three steps to this:

1) Add the `log4j-extras` dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras)

2) Set the layout to EnhancedPatternLayout:
`log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout` (change `stdout` to whatever appender you are using)

3) Add your timezone in braces after your date time pattern
`log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{IST} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n` (Here IST in my case)

You can refer to list of timezone ID's available in java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcs/tag-ref/MISC/TimeZones.html) or [here](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `org.apache.log4j.helpers.DateLayout` as the layout class and the property `timeZone` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Include a `date` argument in your `ConversionPattern`. From the [`PatternLayout` documentation:](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html)

**date** -

> Used to output the date of the logging event in the local time zone.
>   To output the date in universal time use the `%utcdate` pattern. The
>   date conversion specifier may be followed by a date format specifier
>   enclosed between braces. For example, `%date{HH:mm:ss,fff}` or `%date{dd
>   MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff}`. If no date format specifier is given then
>   ISO8601 format is assumed (`Iso8601DateFormatter`).
>
> The date format specifier admits the same syntax as the time pattern
>   string of the `ToString`.
>
> For better results it is recommended to use the log4net date
>   formatters. These can be specified using one of the strings
>   "ABSOLUTE", "DATE" and "ISO8601" for specifying
>   `AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter`, `DateTimeDateFormatter` and respectively
>   `Iso8601DateFormatter`. For example, `%date{ISO8601}` or `%date{ABSOLUTE}`.
>
> These dedicated date formatters perform significantly better than
>   `ToString`.

Comment: Note that this appears to be for .net, not sure it applies to Java--or at least I can't find an equivilent, I'm still looking though.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following line

```
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz}{GMT} %-5p [%t][%c:%M(%L)] %m%n
```