# Timezone change in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: java, timezone, log4j, cloud-foundry

My spring boot application in PCF(Pivotal cloud foundry) shows logs and output of "new Date()" in UTC+5:30, I want to change this timezone to UTC-5:00 (which is CDT). I came across this post : 
[CloudFOundry timezone change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277152/cloudfoundry-timezone)

But after making similiar changes, it doesnt seem to take any effect on my logging timestamp. However I do get the logged "new Date()" output as different and as per that it is

```
2018-09-04T18:40:06.025+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ########## HIT. Tue Sep 04 13:10:06 GMT 2018
```

But this is wrong as well, the new Date() should have printed "Tue Sep 04 **08:10:06 GMT 2018**"

My manifest.yml has below content

```
---
  path: target/VFS-ConfigClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1G
  instances: 1
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
  applications:
  - name: VFS-ConfigClient
    env: 
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: nonProd_test
      TZ: CDT
```

my log4j.properties has below content

```
# Logging Mechanism
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.logger.com.centurylink = INFO, DEBUG, ERROR
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You certainly don’t want `08:10:06 GMT`, that would be all wrong. I think you want `08:10:06 CDT`.

Comment: Instead of `new Date()` use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-5)` or maybe rather `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"))`.

Comment: Hi Ole, yes this will change the application timestamp. Another way>> [ TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago")) ]; I did not want to add this in java layer so found an alternate solution to apply similar fix in manifest file. Thanks for this alternate solution.

Comment: `TimeZone` is the outdated class. I would prefer `ZoneId` if you have the choice. In any case thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it was a manifest change to log right timestamp in cloud foundry. Below is the change that solved it (JAVA_OPTS env variable in the last line). Thanks everyone for helping me.

```
---
  path: target/VFS-ConfigClient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1G
  instances: 1
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
  applications:
  - name: VFS-ConfigClient
    env: 
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: nonProd
      JAVA_OPTS: -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago
```

Comment: This will set the JVM’s time zone at the time it launches. Be aware that it may be changed later by some part of your program or some other program running in the same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain the format in your log4j settings. This [SO Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116425/apache-log4j-logging-with-specific-timezone) has good details

Comment: I have added below two lines to my log4j.properties and have also imported lg4j-extras, but this has no effect on logger timestamps.:/ 

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}{America/Chicago} %p [%c] - %m%n

Comment: The SO forum i cited above works . Am not sure what exact mistake you are doing here