# What are the main differences between EnhancedPatternLayout and PatternLayout?

Tags: java, log4j

While checking the javadoc for PatternLayout, I noticed that it recommends using EnhancedPatternLayout instead. However, it seems to do pretty much the same thing.

What are the main differences, especially the ones I need to be aware of?

I'm also wondering why they made a separate class rather than enhancing the original class. Any syntax differences?

Comment: At least one major difference is the support for time zones - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785725/specify-time-zone-of-log4js-date.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html), everything is explained. `EnhancedPatternLayout` is an enhanced version of `PatternLayout`. It should be used in preference to `PatternLayout` (except for compatibility reason with `PatternLayout`).

[PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) contains some issues which are not present in EnhancedPatternLayout especially with synchronisation.

Comment: I asked this question exactly because I had already checked the documentation and nothing is explained. Yes, it is enhanced, I can see that from its name too, but enhanced **how**?

Comment: So that means EnhancedPatternLayout only has internal changes, but it is used **exactly** the same way?

Comment: Almost, there is some extra conversion characters in `EnhancedPatternLayout` which are not available in PatternLayout. Otherwise it seems to be the same. I am not a Java expert, so you can check by yourself by comparing the two documentation pages and/or sources.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between [PatternLayout](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.java.html) and [EnhancedPatternLayout](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.java.html) is in the format() method. PatternLayout relies on a member field named `sbuf` which it modifies whereas EnhancedPatternLayout uses a private instance of the StringBuffer. This means that PatternLayout.format() calls are susceptible to data races during concurrent calls while concurrent EnhancedPatternLayout.format() calls are not.

Comment: Yes. It is a bit of mystery though under which conditions the `PatternLayout`'s field SB access can cause some real problems - because the calls are `synchronized` anyway - at the `AppenderSkeleton.doAppend()` method (see e. g. sources of log4j 1.2.17). So the `EnhancedPatternLayout` _seems_ to bring unnecessary increased usage of GC. And I've never seen a broken/mixed output in the logs while using `PatternLayout`...

Comment: If the calls are always synchronized, there is potentially some benefit to be had by converting the StringBuffer to StringBuilder in both the layout classes. I am guessing that the append calls are not guaranteed to be synchronized in all scenarios?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the question - when the calls are not guaranteed to be synchronized... Regarding StringBuilder, the Log4j library cannot use this class due to compatibility with older versions of Java which they support...

Answer (score 0):

EnhancedPatternLayout formats the result as a StringBuffer whereas PatternLayout formats the result as a String.

Answer (score 0):

I did a diff on the two HTML pages.

- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

And here are the main differences to me: The intro and two new "conversion character"s: `%properties` and `%throwable`

I have reformatted the text for readability.

## 1. Intro

> This class is an enhanced version of `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`
> which was originally developed as part of the abandoned log4j 1.3
> effort and has been available in the extras companion.
>
> This pattern layout should be used in preference to
> `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` except when compatibility
> where `PatternLayout` has been extended either through subclassing
> or alternative pattern parsers.

## 2. `%properties`

> Used to output the Properties associated
> with the logging event.
>
> The **properties**
> conversion word can be followed by the key for the
> map placed between braces, as in `%properties{application}` where
> `application` is the key. The value in the Properties bundle
> corresponding to the key will be output. If no additional sub-option
> is specified, then the entire contents of the Properties key value pair set
> is output using a format `{{key1,val1},{key2,val2}}`

## 3.`%throwable`

(Reformatted for readability.)

> Used to output the Throwable trace that has been bound to the `LoggingEvent`, by default this will output the full trace as one would normally find by a call to `Throwable.printStackTrace()`.
>
> - `%throwable{short}` or `%throwable{1}` will output the first line of stack trace.
> - `throwable{none}` or `throwable{0}` will suppress the stack trace.
> - `%throwable{n}` will output `n` lines of stack trace if a positive integer or omit the last `-n` lines if a negative integer.
> - If no `%throwable` pattern is specified, the appender will take responsibility to output the stack trace as it sees fit.