# log4j timezones

Tags: java, timezone, log4j

How can i change log4j timezone in log filename?

My log4j.xml file:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"> 
    <appender name="daily" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="logs/cimlib.log" />
    <param name="TimeZone" value="Local" />

    <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z} %p %c: %m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>     

    <root> 
        <priority value ="info" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="daily" /> 
   </root> 
</log4j:configuration>
```

How can i set appender timezone to local?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specify time zone of log4j's date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785725/specify-time-zone-of-log4js-date)

Comment: sorry, but i want to use local timezones in filename

Answer (score 0):

This is not a settable variable.  It uses your machine's date/time/zone.