# How do I set the TimeZone to GMT/UTC in Jetty StdErr/StdOut

Tags: jetty

The console output is in local time for some reason. I want to redirect it to a file and save it, but I need it to correspond with the request log. I have tried so many things, I cannot believe it can be this difficult.

It seems more logical for a web server to use UTC, but Jetty stdout/stderr keeps outputting local time.

It's so frustrating, because the request log gets it right o_O

**UPDATE:** (Per Michael's suggestion below) Place the following in Jetty's start.ini file.

```
--exec
-Duser.timezone="GMT"
```

I haven't tried this on linux yet, I will post an update when I figure out how to do it there. The steps may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing logical in having the log in UTC. Logging in local time is what is logical and broadly accepted everywhere. If you really need it in UTC, then the logical thing is to set the server's time zone to UTC, or JVM's timezone to UTC:
`java -Duser.timezone="UTC"`
if you only need logging in UTC, you need to setup the logger, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785851/525906

Comment: We have one server in Mesa and one on the East coast, with mobile users located everywhere. We always prefer to store time in UTC, in the DB, log files, everywhere possible. Because, that time will correlate across the entire organization. It can then be rendered in any time zone the viewer resides in.

Comment: Your suggestion about the JVM time zone works nicely, when placed into the Jetty start.ini, preceeded by "--exec". This spawns a new JVM, with the desired time zone.