# Incorrect timezone in log4j logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am running a java program on the server where timezone is set to CST, however log4j logs are writing time in GMT timezone instead of CST timezone.

Below is my log4j conversion pattern

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss} [%-7p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I've tried below conversion pattern but it didn't worked:

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}{GMT+6} [%-7p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}{CST} [%-7p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss}{US/Central} [%-7p] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785725/specify-time-zone-of-log4js-date

Comment: Thank you! @Jens :)

Log4j Extra jar was missing, adding that resolved my issue.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Please post the answer and mark resolved :)